# What are "3D X-MOUNTING Screw Pillars" for?

Tags: motherboard

I am building a threadripper workstation, and I found an unexpected packet of screw pillars supplied with the msi X399 GAMING PRO CARBON AC motherboard. The manual describes them as "3D X-MOUNTING Screw Pillars" but makes no mention of how to use them (I searched the digital manual and found nothing). Does anyone know what they are for? They look like motherboard standoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what they are for?

Based on the specifications of the motherboard:

> This motherboard features X-mounting 3D printing screws which allow
>   you to use your own 3D printed covers, FAN guards or other 3D printed
>   materials to mounted to the board with ease.

Source: [MSI X399 GAMING PRO CARBON AC sTR4 AMD X399 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 ATX AMD Motherboard](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813144079)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a place where you can download some 3d parts for the board. Says 299 but they work on the x399 board too:

https://www.msi.com/Landing/mod-hub/